# replace (a+b)*3+7 by (aplusb)*3+7 in java?

Tags: java, regex, replace

i think the question is in the title ,

i already tried matcher and pattern, with this regex `\\((.*?)\\)` but it gets me just the string between the brackets without `*3` ,

how i can to transform this : `(a+b)*3+7`
to this : `(aplusb)*3+7`

i tried the replace all but it replaces me the '+' out of brackets too, and i get this `(aplusb)*3plus7`
but i want to replace it like i said to this : `(aplusb)*3+7`

i tried many methods before asking , so please help me 
thanx for helping and sorry for my weak english :)

Comment: Do you want to replace, '+' which are located in the parenthesis؟

Comment: Can you be more specific about when you want to replace `+` with `plus`? Should it be only inside parenthesis, or maybe if it is not surrounded by numbers, or maybe there is other rule like "replace first `+` we find"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the below regex and then replace the matched symbol `+` with `plus` . Since `+` is a regex meta character, you need to escape it inorder to match a literal `+` symbol.

```
\+(?=[^()]*\))
```

The above regex would match the symbol `+` only if it's followed by,

- `[^()]*` Any character but not of `(` or `)` zero or more times.
- `\)` Further followed by a closing bracket.
- `(?=...)` Called [positive lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) which asserts whether match would occur or not. This won't consume any character.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nU9zV0/1)

```
System.out.println("(a+b)*3+7".replaceAll("\\+(?=[^()]*\\))", "plus"));
```

Output:

```
(aplusb)*3+7
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not use [String.replaceFirst()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))?

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s="(a+b)*3+7";
        System.out.println(s.replaceFirst("\\+","plus"));

    }
}
```

Results in: (aplusb)*3+7